# lists: index of lowest value and reorder

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
foo =
[[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5],
 [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5],
 [c1, c2, c3, c4, c5]]
# in real: many more rows & columns
```

every a_i, b_i and c_i contains 3 values: [x,y,z]

now I want to reorder the entrys this way::
I want to get the index of the a-column where I have the lowest y-value. let's say, in example, in a3 there is the lowest y-value of all a's.
so I want to reorder my list this way:

```
[[a3, a4, a5, a1, a2],
 [b3, b4, b5, b1, b2],
 [c3, c4, c5, c1, c2]]
```

-> so I don't care about the other y-values, only want to know the lowest one and set this at the first position of my list and keep the sequence (a5 after a4 after a3...) alive -> the values which where in the original list before a3 (a1 and a2) shall appended in the end.

I know I can get the lowest y-value of the first column with this:

```
xmin, ymin, zmin = map(min, zip(*foo[0]))
print ymin
```

But I don't need the value, but the index. And how can I reorder my list without a for-loop?

Edit:
Reason for not using a for-loop:
It's a huge list and I'm looking for a more efficient way. But I would also accept a for-loop.

Comment: To be clear you are saying `a1 = [x,y,z]`? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, as mhlester said: It's a list of lists of lists.

Comment: Why can't you use a loop? That seems like a rather silly restriction to me.

Comment: yes, I didn't see that edit...

Comment: @Munchkin Your specification is still unclear. If you only "set [the lowest y-value] at the first position of the list", your list would be ordered as `[a3, a1, a2, a4, a5]`, which is not what you have written in your question.

Comment: big sorry, your downvote is correct. I edited my question. Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find the appropriate index then use a list comprehension:

```
from operator import itemgetter

# first get index from first row
min_index = min(enumerate(foo[0]), key=lambda x: x[1][1])[0]

# then apply to all rows
foo = [item[min_index:] + item[:min_index] for item in foo]
```

Note that this *will* loop, but any code you write to do this will at some point!

Comment: OP asks for "reorder...without a loop".  (so your answer should probably be "you can't...".  :)

Comment: This doesn't work the way OP wants it to. You're sorting each row individually, rather than sorting only the first row and bringing the other columns into line with the sorted first row.

Comment: ooohhh, sorry, loop is okay, I just wanted to know how I can do it without a *for*-loop

Comment: I tested it: It does not work as axpected: As I said, I *don't* want to sort it by the y-value, but only get to know the lowest one, set it at the first position and sequence (of original list) shall be kept. In your example the sequence isn't kept =/

Comment: I think you need to edit your question. I interpreted it as being that you wanted to order the first row by `y` values, then use that ordering for *all* rows. Please be explicit about your specification.

Comment: @Munchkin Your question was not clear about that. Please edit to clarify.

Comment: How's that, any better?

Comment: The way of sorting the list looks correct, but your code searches for x_min, not y_min.

Comment: Are you sure? `enumerate` gives tuples `(index, value)`, then value is `[x, y, z]`, hence `itemgetter(1 [for value], 1 [for y])`.

Comment: take the example grid from stewSquared's answer and change the very first value, test[0][0][0], into -1. you will get "0" as index, not "3".

Comment: but it's no problem anymore; i just figured out that I also can work with a grid sorted by x_min =)

Comment: Apologies, I made a mistake with `itemgetter`. I have fixed this using `lambda`, but I'm glad you've sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a list of lists of lists; I'm assuming the outer list stays the same.

```
for row in foo:
    row.sort(key=lambda x:min(*x))
```

The main takeaway is to sort with a lambda key, and the `min(*x)` takes the min of all the values in list x

You have to loop through foo, but that's to be expected.

Comment: This sorts each row individually. Every row should be sorted the same way, ie., by the second element of the elements of the first row.

Answer (score 0):

A numpy based solution.

```
import numpy as np
foo = np.random.randint(0,100,(3,5))    #some random data for testing
print foo                               #original order
i = np.argmin(foo[1,:])                 #find min index of second row
foo[:,[0,i]] = foo[:,[i,0]]             #swap columns to move selected row to front
print foo                               #new order
```

Or in case you decide you would like to sort the entire row, and don't mind the slightly higher computational load:

```
import numpy as np
foo = np.random.randint(0,100,(3,5))    #some random data for testing
print foo                               #original order
foo = foo[:,np.argsort(foo[1])]         #complete sorting by second row
print foo                               #new order
```

Either way, both of these will blow a pure python based solution out of the water, in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

Easy: To sort columns by first element, flip along diagonal, sort rows by first element, flip back.

```
def diagFlip(grid):
    return [[grid[i][j] for i in range(len(grid))] for j in range(len(grid[0]))]

def sortByColumnTops(grid):
    grid = diagFlip(grid)
    grid.sort(key=(lambda row: row[0][1]))
    return diagFlip(grid)
```

And to prove it works:

```
test = [[[0,4,0],[0,2,0],[0,3,0],[0,1,0]],
        [[0,1,0],[0,3,0],[0,2,0],[0,4,0]],
        [[0,1,0],[0,2,0],[0,3,0],[0,4,0]]]
test = sortByColumnTops(test)

for row in test: print(row)
```

yields

```
[[0, 1, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 3, 0], [0, 4, 0]]
[[0, 4, 0], [0, 3, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
[[0, 4, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 3, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
```